# Create Ngx-Formly Custom Template for Radio Type

Tags: angular, angular-formly

> **How to create a custom radio template in ngx-formly ?**
>
> Had reviewed the [Ngx-Formly Guide for Custom Templates on FormlyField](https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field)
>
> Though had successfully created a custom template for **input** but i can't seem to achieve it on **radio**
>
> Currently, i had it implemented like this:

**FormlyFieldRadio**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'formly-field-radio', 
  template: `
    <input type="radio" 
           [formControl]="formControl" 
           [formlyAttributes]="field">
  `,
   styles: [``]
})
export class FormlyFieldRadio extends FieldType {}
```

**LandingModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ...
     FormlyFieldInput,
     FormlyFieldRadio
  ],
  imports: [
     ...
     FormlyModule.forRoot({
        types: [
           { name: 'input', component: FormlyFieldInput },
           { name: 'radio', component: FormlyFieldRadio }
        ]
     })
  ]
})
export class AppLandingModule {}
```

**FormlyField Data**

```
const fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
   ...,
   {
      key: 'gender',
      type: 'radio',
      templateOptions: {
        name: 'gender',
        options: [{ value: 'Male', key: 'M' }, { value: 'Female', key: 'F' }]
      }
  }
];
```

Any suggestions / solution is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had an existing [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-radio) in regards to this matter.

You can implement a custom radio template by filling-in your **FormlyFieldRadio** with its corresponding loop, assignments and data. Not just a simple input type element with the same format as of FormlyFieldInput

**FormlyFieldRadio**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'formly-field-radio',
 template: `
  <div *ngFor="let option of to.options">          
    <input type="radio" 
           [name]="to.name"
           [formControl]="formControl" 
           [formlyAttributes]="field"
           [value]="option.key">
    {{ option.value }}
  </div>
 `,
})
export class FormlyFieldRadio extends FieldType {}
```

> It seems like the `to, formControl and field` are already a reserved
>   variables inside the ngx-formly that you could utilized based on the [ngx-formly library radio file](https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly/blob/master/src/ionic/src/lib/types/radio.ts) which my solution was inspired to.

Comment: +1 for this is the comment that taught me that to access the templateOptions config variables, I need to use a variable called "to". I could not find direct documentation of stuff like this anywhere. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you've unnecessarily added things to declarations in your `@NgModule`. You should be good to go with this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {FormlyModule} from '@ngx-formly/core';
import {FormlyBootstrapModule} from '@ngx-formly/bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyModule.forRoot(),
    FormlyBootstrapModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in your Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyFieldConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h3>@ngx-formly/bootstrap</h3>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(model)">
      <formly-form [model]="model" [fields]="fields">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </formly-form>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model = { email: 'email@gmail.com' };
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'email',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'email',
        label: 'Email address',
        placeholder: 'Enter email',
        required: true,
      }
    }, {
      key: 'gender',
      type: 'radio',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'Gender',
        required: true,
        name: 'gender',
        options: [{ value: 'Male', key: 'M' }, { value: 'Female', key: 'F' }]
      }
    }
  ];

  submit(user) {
    console.log(user);
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-bootstrap-sample-with-radio-button?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

---

**Note:** I'm using the UI-Bootstrap Module for integration.

Comment: Hi sidd, I appreciate your help but currently Im not using the default template that the ngx-formly/core & ngx-formly/bootstrap has. Instead had tried to implement a custom template with my own css and template structure in relevance on styling my form fields and also had read it to this ngx-formly custom template documentation as well though the radio is not documented here https://formly-js.github.io/ngx-formly/guide/custom-formly-field