# Use @ngx-formly with custom radio component (internal UI components)

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I am working with a custom radio components and I'm having a hard time connecting the component to the form using formly v5.

This is how I would use the custom radio component

```html
<custom-radio
  name="regular"
  value="1"
  label="Regular"
>
</custom-radio>
```

The above code renders the following HTML, which I am oversimplifying

```html
<custom-radio>
  <label>
    <input type="radio">
    <span class="faux-radio">
      Regular
    </span>
  </label>
</custom-radio>
```

My formly configuration is the following

#### Formly Module

```
FormlyModule.forRoot({
   types: [
    {
      name: "custom-radio",
      component: FormlyCustomRadio, // This is my new formly wrapper component 
    }
   ],
}),
```

#### Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'formly-custom-radio',
  template: `
     <custom-radio
        *ngFor="let option of to.options"
        [formControl]="formControl"
        [formlyAttributes]="field"
        [name]="to.name"
        [value]="option.key"
        [label]="option.label"
   >
   </custom-radio>
   `
})
export class FormlyCustomRadio extends FieldType<FieldTypeConfig> {}
```

#### FormlyFieldConfig data

```
const fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: "dog",
      type: "custom-radio",
      templateOptions: {
        label: "Do you have a dog?",
        name: "dog",
        options: [
          { key: "1", label: "Yes" },
          { key: "2", label: "No" },
        ],
      },
    },
]
```

The form renders properly but there is a error in the console and the form model does not contain the value selected in the form's radio button

```bash
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
```

My spider sense is telling me that is has to do with `formControl` and the inability to find an input within `custom-radio` component as it hides the input from `fromly`

I'd like to not go the [native path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738269/create-ngx-formly-custom-template-for-radio-type) to solve this, since I'd have to rewrite the component's styles, inputs, and events.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most adequate way to solve this, but with it I was able to get and set form control

- `ngDefaultControl` - added Angular property to custom component
- `formControl` - use this property provided by `formly` to get and set value

  - note the use of `formControl.value` and `formControl.setValue()`
- `[model]` - custom component binding represents the current selection of the radio component
- `(select)` - custom component output binding emits whenever the radio button is selected

The new template will look like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'formly-custom-radio',
  template: `
     <custom-radio
        *ngFor="let option of to.options"
        ngDefaultControl
        [label]="option.label"
        [model]="formControl.value"
        [name]="to.name"
        (select)="formControl.setValue($event)"
        [value]="option.key"
        
   >
   </custom-radio>
   `
})
export class FormlyCustomRadio extends FieldType<FieldTypeConfig> {}
```